# Handling Errors with Grails and jQuery

Tags: jquery, grails

I am working to try to handle errors gracefully with Grails and jQuery.  I want to return a 400 if a validation error occurs when trying to save an object and have the jQuery fail callback fire in order to handle it.  We have been setting the status to 400 in the response and rendering it but that doesn't appear to be working.  After looking at some error handling questions maybe the 400 is used to indicate an error at the transport level and not a web application error.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST
render(response as JSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an ajax call? You can handle specific error codes like...

```
...
statusCode:{
    400: function() {
        alert( 'Got a 400' );
    }
},
...
```

I think the setting of the error code in the response is fine, not sure about rendering it as JSON though, if it works for you go for it, otherwise just return your error message as a string or a map of stuff or whatever.

The following will invoke the block:

```
def myAction() {
    response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST
    render('This will invoke the 400 handler')
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delayed response.  Do you know how to get the fail promise to fire?

Comment: I added an action to the answer that will hit the 400 handler